# How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a knockoutjs background?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, knockout.js

**How do I “think in [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/)” if I have a [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) background?**

Suppose I'm familiar with developing *client-side applications* in Knockoutjs, but now I'd like to start using AngularJS. Can you describe the paradigm shift that is necessary ? Here are a few questions that might help you frame an answer:

- How can i use the similarities of **KnockoutJs** to learn **AngularJs** ?
- What should I stop doing/using; what should I start doing/using instead?

I'm not looking for a detailed comparison between knockoutJs and AngularJS.

all i need is to learn AngularJS with the knowledge of KnockoutJs (like observable, Computed, subscribe etc.,) and also suggest some good articles for AngularJS

Help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: One neat thing I saw in angular is that scope use prototype inheritance. In ko, constantly I have to call `$parent.something` or `$root.something`, but in angular, it's just `something` no matter whether it's on current scope or parent scope.

Comment: On the other hand, angular doesn't have ko's automatic dependency tracking, I have to explicitly define what to track in `$scope.$watch`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea is largely the same, but Angular uses Plain Old JavaScript objects instead of explicit observable functions, so you avoid the method syntax when you refer to properties.